# Magento 2 : 2FA - Google Auth Image Not working Properly in admin

Tags: magento2, permissions, two-factor-authentication

I am using Magento 2 Instance and while login in to the admin panel I am facing 2FA - Google Auth Not Looking properly. Please check in below Image.

[image]

Comment: I would open Network tab in browser and see error response for this QR code image. Maybe you can provide sample admin credentials to see?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix: Disable TwoFactorAuth module using below command:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Then execute the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you are able to login/use the admin of your Magento 2 store.

Comment: Thats Ok but I want to login with Magento_TwoFactorAuth and QR Code image not showing .